# Blur event doesn't fire when navigating away from input field

Tags: jquery

When I move out of my input field the blur function doesn't fire.

Any idea's?

```
<input type="text" value="test" id="webshop_product_url_part" name="setting" class="is"/>

jQuery("input.is").live("blur", function(){
            console.log("2");
            conslole.log("asdf");

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`live` uses event delegation to work. This means that only events that bubble can take advantage of it. Events that do no bubble, and therefore cannot utilize event delegation (jQuery's live), include blur and focus, among others.

The only way around this is to bind the event to every element. When you append and element, bind it then. You could also write a plugin of sorts that adds parameters to jQuery's `append`, allowing you to specify an event and it's associated handler for all elements that match your selector.

Answer (score 1):

Looking on jQuery [`live()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) documentation

> Binds a handler
> to an event (like click) for all
> current - and future - matched
> element. Can also bind custom events.
>
> **Possible event values:** click,
> dblclick, mousedown, mouseup,
> mousemove, mouseover, mouseout,
> keydown, keypress, keyup
>
> #### Currently not supported: blur, focus,
> mouseenter, mouseleave, change, submit

Comment: Presumably you're using live() because you're dynamically adding the input. if not, obviously use blur() or bind("blur", ... ). the only way currently would be to set up the event handler after adding the input to the DOM. If you're using append(), it will return the appended elements, therefore you can chain blur on afterwards